# How to adjust heights of listbox inside a frame in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas, listboxitem

I am trying to create a frame to just include the list boxes to the right of the canvas on so I can adjust their geometry separately of the canvas (as I need to place another frame underneath this with different widgets) AND also to place the canvas and this new frame inside a main frame to I can position everything better on the screen with padding - any suggestions on either of these problems (or better ways) would be really good as its just completely confusing me now!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
my_window = Tk()
my_window.geometry('1000x500+200+200')
my_canvas = Canvas(my_window, width=500, height=500, bg='BLUE')
my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)


frame_name = Frame(my_window, bg='GREEN')
#frame_name.geometry('200x200')
frame_name.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

my_blank_canvas = Canvas(frame_name, width=50, height=500, bg='Green')
my_blank_canvas.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2)

listbox_objects = Listbox(frame_name)
listbox_objects .grid(row=0, column=1)
listbox_objects_filtered = Listbox(frame_name)
listbox_objects_filtered .grid(row=0, column=3)

listbox_events = Listbox(frame_name)
listbox_events.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=20)
listbox_events_filtered = Listbox(frame_name)
listbox_events_filtered.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=20)

frame_name.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)


my_list_objects = ['1', '2', '3']
for item in my_list_objects:
    listbox_objects.insert(END, item)

my_list_events = ['1', '2', '3']
for item in my_list_events:
    listbox_events.insert(END, item)


my_list_objects_filtered = ['1', '2', '3']
for item in my_list_objects_filtered:
    listbox_objects_filtered.insert(END, item)

my_list_events_filtered = ['1', '2', '3']
for item in my_list_events_filtered:
    listbox_events_filtered.insert(END, item)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed this now. I used the height and width parameters to alter the size of the frame_name